# parametrizing pagination for a query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've got a complex query like this:

`VERSION1`

```
export async function mPass(){
   return await MyModel.aggregate()
           .addField({$match: {//condition}})
           .lookup(//lookup query)
           .addField({$cond: {//condition}})
           .addField(//condition2)  #<---------PAGINATE DATA HERE
           .addField({$match: {//condition}})
}
```

now, for the same query, I'm required to paginate the results , but, I am to paginate data after `condition2` above

so, the above function would become something like this:

`VERSION2`

```
export async function mPass(pageNumber, pageSize){
   return await MyModel.aggregate()
           .addField({$match: {//condition}})
           .lookup(//lookup query)
           .addField({$cond: {//condition}})
           .addField(//condition2)  # <---------PAGINATE DATA HERE
           .skip((pageNumber-1)*pageSize)
           .limit(pageSize)
           .addField({$match: {//condition}})
}
```

the problem is, I've already used the function multiple places which don't require pagination. So, I was thinking there was something like this:

```
.skip(-1).limit(-1)
```

which would not do any skipping or limiting, but, turned to the docs and it says they both take positive values only.

So, how would I approach to parametrize the function to optionally include pagination in the query at the specified place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [if](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) statement:

```
export async function mPass(pageNumber = null, pageSize = null){
   let ag = MyModel.aggregate()
           .addField({$match: {//condition}})
           .lookup(//lookup query)
           .addField({$cond: {//condition}})
           .addField(//condition2)  # <---------PAGINATE DATA HERE
   if (pageSize) {
       ag.skip((pageNumber-1)*pageSize)
           .limit(pageSize)
   }
   return ag.addField({$match: {//condition}})
}
```

As a side note, $match after pagination is a questionable practice. You may end up with a page with less than pageSize documents, or even without documents at all.

Comment: how does the await syntax work with aggregate? Does it force to calculate the result? what if I have say 50 such if conditions, would the aggregation have been calculated say half way through till it reached say, the 30th statement?

Comment: Yes, in 2 words it does. No, it won't be calculated half-way. Explanation would rather be lengthy. Starting from async/await statements is a syntax sugar on Promises. Then I'd need to explain that mongoose uses own implementation of [Promises](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html). Then we'd need to dive deep into fluent interface of aggregation when it's attached to a model. Basically it builds the normal aggregate([<whole pipeline with all stages>]) and implicitly calls [exec()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate-exec) at the end.

Comment: but, why can't we return the query without an `await` and use that outside chaining additional queries as necessary? e.g. `mPass().addField()` if mPass returned without an await?

Comment: ah, good point, no need to await the return. I just copy-pasted the original code focusing on the changes related to the question. I updated the answer. Regarding `mPass().addField()` - are you sure you understand that order of stages matter? I would rather `return ag.exec()` to ensure no more stages added to the result of the function.

Comment: hm... I meant if it was possible to store a query as a function making it reusable?

Comment: Sure you can. Technically. You should have very good reasons to do so tho. If it is only for the sake of DRY principles - I wouldn't recommend it, but it's slightly off-topic. As I said pagination in the middle of the pipline doesn't make any sense to me at the first place, so I'll leave your usecase to you and focus on the question about conditional stage depending on parameters. If my post answers that question, consider marking it as such.